# How to uninstall GHC 7.x from FreeBSD?

Tags: haskell, uninstall, freebsd, downgrade

I have installed GHC 7.x on FreeBSD, (installed with binary distribution, not `pkg_add`) but I have to downgrade it to 6.x.
How can I uninstall it? Or is there general method to uninstall program on unix-like from OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've installed a package using ports, then you can uninstall it using the command [`pkd_delete(1)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg_delete&sektion=1), otherwise you should remove files manually.

Comment: I agree there's no other way than manual removing :(